# Crop the images from camera screen android

Tags: android, crop

I want to develop a camera screen which consists of a camera with the frame (see the first image). When I take the photo I don't need the full image, I need only the portion of the image present inside the frame (see the second image).

[image]

[image]

I tried many image crop libraries in github. 
https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

I also tried with intent to call crop

```
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

These are not helping me to crop the image inside the frame. I don't want crop screen separately. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that frame is an another image?

Comment: Why not create an Activity with a Camera 2 API, create an Overlay using a Drawable border XML file and then crop the image accordingly to that border just after the shoot?

Comment: Yes. the frame is another image above camera layout. @SanthoshJoseph

Comment: Can you send any reference link @emandt

Comment: Any solution for this? I have some problem

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom camera using surface and try this hope result is as you want

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

Camera mCamera;
SurfaceView mPreview; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
    mPreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mPreview.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mCamera = Camera.open();
}   
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mCamera.stopPreview();
}    
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mCamera.release();
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {       
    Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(4); //480h x 720w

    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {                        
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    } else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
    }

    mCamera.startPreview();
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i("PREVIEW","surfaceDestroyed");
}
}
```

and your xml looks like

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  </FrameLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="400px"
        android:layout_marginTop="300px"
        android:layout_marginStart="70px"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70px"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <!---Customize your views and button-->

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and your `manifests.xml` and if you are using above of android version 5.1 add runtime permission or you can check by manually grant permission from app settings

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and the response is above code

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Did you try this code? it is not working, you named both FrameLayout and SurfaceView id as preview

Comment: I am using it and by mistake i added it check now i removed it edit frame as you want

Comment: Exception on line 90: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.SurfaceHolder android.view.SurfaceView.getHolder()'

Comment: Please run your code once before posting the answer

Comment: Yes permission is there

Comment: which android version you are using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177993/discussion-between-vignes-and-sandeep-parish).

Answer (score 2):

Well. Try this.

```
    int[] location = new int[2];
    iv_frame.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int x = location[0];
    int y = location[1];

    Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, x, y, iv_frame.getMeasuredWidth() + 160, iv_frame.getMeasuredHeight() + 160); // Adjust the 160 according to your need. In my case the frame has a fixed length and width
```

Take picture -> Call this function with the camera result data -> Save the resulting bitmap :)

Comment: I am checking this

Comment: Try it. I can help you more on this.

Comment: It is cropping the image but it is not properly cropping inside frame

Comment: Actually, my frame is LinearLayout

Comment: Adjust the "160" as mentioned in code. Hope it helps. As it is already cropping, now we need to take care of measurement.

Comment: Did you got it? Need any more help?

Comment: No, I didt get it.

Comment: Update your question then I can help you. :)

Comment: Can you help me with same problem?

Answer (score -3):

This library should do the trick 
I use it all the time . It works

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4760

It allows you to take picture from either gallery or camera with crop support and you don't need to write much code to get it to work
;-)

Comment: Please understand my question clearly. I don't need crop functionality separately. I need inside the frame image should be cropped while taking the photo.

Comment: Oh ok. So sorry. Let me get back to you