# How to capture only a portion of camera(like rectangle oval) in android using CameraX

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

Just need to capture the Rectangular portion on the screen and ignore all that is outside of the Rectangel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [capture overlay using PreviewView of cameraX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64903838/capture-overlay-using-previewview-of-camerax)

Comment: @Sniffer Seems different, this isn't trying to capture the overlay, but rather the portion **within** the rectangle.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51835370/5978440)